# mongoose findById query not executing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For a Node project of mine, I'm using mongoose to store/access the user model. In my index.js file, I initialize everything:

```
const restify = require('restify')
const Router = require('./lib/routing/Router.js')

const server = restify.createServer()
server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser())

// init global variable
global.one = {}

// init database
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/oneboard1')

mongoose.set('debug', true)
mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error('MongoDB error: %s', err);
});

// init ORM
const models = require('./models.js')
one.model = models

// init middleware
const ClassAuthMiddleware = require('./middleware/AuthMiddleware')
const authMiddleware = new ClassAuthMiddleware()

// register routes
const rtr = new Router(server)
rtr.get('/user/profile', 'AuthController.getProfile').middleware('pre', authMiddleware)
rtr.post('/user/create', 'AuthController.createUser')
rtr.post('/user/auth', 'AuthController.issueToken')

rtr.bind()

server.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('%s listening at %s', "OneBoard Server", server.url)
})

// a sanity check
one.model.User.findById('5b0b256b044e0e0274b4367c')
    .then(user => console.log(user))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

My models.js file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

module.exports = {
    User: mongoose.model('User', {
        email: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
        },
        password: String,
        clips: { type: [], default: [] },
        created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    }),
}
```

The routes to authenticate and create a user work perfectly. Also, running User.findById works perfectly in the index.js file and returns the user object. However, I have written some Auth middleware. In this ware, I try to query the User model using the same ID that is in the index.js sanity check. However, this time, the findById function just doesn't execute! I've turned mongoose debugging on, and it doesn't run any commands when I execute the findById function, despite it showing up as a function in the User object when tested. Here is the middleware file:

```
const Middleware = require('../lib/routing/Middleware')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const authHelper = require('auth-header')
const config = require('../config.js')

class AuthMiddleware extends Middleware {
    exec( req, res, breakChain, next ){
        const auth = authHelper.parse(req.header('authorization'))

        jwt.verify( auth.token, config.auth.jwtSecret, ( error, decoded ) => {
            console.log(decoded) // works
            console.log({_id: decoded.id}) // works
            console.log(one.model.User.findById) //works
            one.model.User.findById(decoded.id) // does nothing
                .then(user => console.log(user)) // doesn't execute
                .catch(error => console.log(error)) // doesn't execute

            console.log('post MW') // works

        })
    }
}


module.exports = AuthMiddleware
```

I have been trying to debug this for hours now, and I'm sure it's something simple, but for the life of me I can't figure out why mongoose won't run the findById query. (For the record, I have checked that the name of the collection lines up with the name of the model.)

Comment: Did you import user model?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The User model is stored in the one.model global variable. console.log(one.model.User) shows the actual model, so it is there.

Comment: put your query outside the class and check whether it works or not

Comment: It does. So is it possible that it has something to do with the loading of mongoose/when Node inits the class?

Comment: I don't know but you can avoid class... use simply module.export